# Finding the inverse of a composition

Tags: functions, inverse

> Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow A$ be 1-1 and onto. Identify $(g \circ f)^{-1}$.

First I need to identify the inverse, then prove it qualifies as the inverse.

These types of functions are very difficult to understand.  If I have a function that goes from A to B does that mean the inverse is just from B to A?  It can't be that simple.  I don't know even know where to start with this.

Comment: Hint: $g\circ f$ is a function from $A\to B\to A$, so it is a function from $A\to A$. Hence, the inverse is also a function from $A\to A$. Intuitively, if I applied $f$ and then $g$, to undo it, I first undo $g$, then undo $f$. How do I write that in function form?

Comment: @DonThousand I'm honestly still confused.  Would I write that $f(g(x))$?